# Unable to find the auto created Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created simple ASP.NET MVC4 application using EntityFramework Code first approach. The entity class is as below:

```
public class Album
{
    [Key]
    public int AblumId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

}

public class MusicContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

And the `web.config` connection details are as below

```
 <connectionStrings> 
    <add name="MusicContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

The application runs fine and I am able to add, delete, edit the album records but I am unable to find the database. When I checked the SQL server instance using SSMS there is no database created. I have not specified "Initial Catalog" value (DBName) in the web.config and not given DBname during Context creation in the code. I even checked the DB Name at run time, but it returns empty string as shown in the screen shot below. I even checked the SQL Express, no DBs created there and not even on my other instance. So where can I find the auto created DB. I am sure DB is stored somewhere because the records are stored and retrieved without any errors.

[image]

Comment: check in app_data, make sure to click 'show all files'

Comment: @Roman thanks for replying. I have already checked the APP_Data folder, the directory is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify a database name then the connection will use the default database for the user, in this case it's integrated security so it's your Windows login. As you likely have full system admin on the server the default database will be `master` so you will find all your tables in there.

For a little more clarification, `master` is a system database and as such, to see it in SSMS you will need to navigate to `Server` -> `Databases` -> `System Databases`.

To fix this problem you can either:

1. Specify the database name in the connection string.
2. Change the default database for your user.

I would recommend specifying the database name though, unless you have a need to dynamically change the database for the login, then it's always better to be explicit about things like this.

Comment: that was an excellent explanation. I will check the master database , unfortunately I can do that only by tomorrow.I will reply back once I get access tomorrow. But I am curious to know why is the database name displayed as  empty string in the watch window while debugging the code?

Comment: The database name is what you specified in the connection string, not what the connection is connecting to. Remember that the current database can change.

Comment: Oh ok , thanks for clarifying :) Will check the master DB .

Comment: you were right, the tables are created inside the master database :) . I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's created a local DB inside the solution. Goto View and select Server Explorer then look in the Data Connections Drop down.